# Revoke Activation of Visio 2010 Product Key

Tags: microsoft-office, license-key, software-activation

I'm moving my work computer from my old laptop to a newer one. I recently installed Visio 2010 on my now old computer a few weeks ago to work with some files. I plan on reformatting this machine. I installed Visio 2010 on my new machine but got a message that the product key has been activated the max number of times that the license allows. We have a bunch of people at work using it -- I think it may be a 10 or 15 person license. Can I somehow revoke my license from my old machine to free up that activation so I can use it on my new one? Since I plan on reformatting, it seems like a wasted activation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to contact Microsoft - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/about-visio-activation-HP085052827.aspx

Here is the page for activation (since it can be hard sometimes finding this on a website the size of Microsofts...) http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=326851

Answer (score 0):

You will likley have to call Microsoft and explain the situation.  It us usually quite painless at least in North America.  However, call too many times and ther ewill be an issue.